# Reset initial condition of ODEINT integration program

Tags: c++, numerical-integration, odeint

I have these codes in main function of my odeint program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    modelInit();

    double v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16;
    v1=1-pow(WB/param[WM],0.25);
    v2=0;
    v3=pow(WB/param[WM],0.25);
    v4=0;
    v5=0;
    v6=0;
    v7 =WB; //kg nonlabile weight
    v8 =XB; //kg labile weight
    v9 =WB;
    v10 =XB;
    v11=0; //kg (gravid uterus weight)
    v12=delta*WB;// kg (digestive tract content weight)
    v13=0; //MJ
    v14=0;//MJ
    v15=0;//Kg
    v16=0;


    double conception;
    double calving;
    double dry_off=60;
    afm f=read_afm();


    state_type x= {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16};// initial conditions
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type > rk_dopri5;   // error stepper
    typedef controlled_runge_kutta< rk_dopri5 > ctrl_rk_dopri5; // controlled stepper


    conception = param[nubile_duration];
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, 0.0, conception-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                         //from birth to first conception//


   x[1]=0.001;
   x[3]=ev_epsilon;
   calving = conception+param[pi];
   integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, conception, calving-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                       //from conception to just before calving//

    param[eD]=energy_density();
    parity=1;
    x[3]=0;
    x[4]=val;
    not_milk=0;
    x[5]=2.49127154617638E-12;
    conception = calving+f.pc1;
    is_milking_b = true;
    //dim=0;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, calving, conception-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                    //from calving to second conception//
    cout<<"pc1="<<f.pc1<<endl;

    x[3]=ev_epsilon;
    dry_off=conception+param[pi]-dry_off;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, conception, dry_off-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                    //from second conception to just before dry_off//


    not_milk=1; //not_milking is true
    is_milking_b = false;
    calving=conception+param[pi];
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, dry_off, calving-1, 1.0, ode_write); //you are here
                                                        //from dry_off to just before second calving//


    parity++;
    dim=0;
    x[3]=0;
    x[4]=val;
    not_milk=0;
    is_milking_b = true;
    conception=calving+f.pc2;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, calving, conception-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                       //from second calving to third conception

    x[3]=ev_epsilon;
    dry_off=conception+param[pi]-60;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, conception, dry_off-1, 1.0, ode_write);


    is_milking_b = false;
    not_milk=1; //not_milking is true
    calving=conception+param[pi];
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, dry_off, calving-1, 1.0, ode_write); //you are here
                                                        //from dry_off to just before second calving//


    parity++;
    is_milking_b = true;
    dim=0;
    x[3]=0;
    x[4]=val;
    not_milk=0;
    conception=calving+f.pc3;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, calving, conception-1, 1.0, ode_write);
                                                      //from second calving to third conception


    x[3]=ev_epsilon;
    dry_off=conception+param[pi]-60;
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, conception, dry_off-1, 1.0, ode_write);

    is_milking_b = false;
    not_milk=1; //not_milking is true
    calving=conception+param[pi];
    integrate_const( ctrl_rk_dopri5(), ode_system, x, dry_off, calving-1, 1.0, ode_write); //you are here
                                                        //from dry_off to just before second calving//
```

As you can see, I am trying to reset the initial condition of x by separating integration time step manually. However, it seems so trivial by doing this way I think. I have been trying to think a better way of doing that but could not succeed. Could you please give me some helps/hints.
Thanks you very much.
Phuong

Comment: Why you don't use a std::vector with double?

Comment: @Android400: you meant std::vector<double> v? Yes, I can do this but it still does not solve my "trivial" problem of copy-paste the odeint function each period of time when I want to reset the condition.